# PHP foreach($_POST as $key => $value) windows server 2003 IIS 6 problem

Tags: php, windows, post, get, foreach

In my database connection include I use the code

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
  $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value); 
} 
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { 
  $_GET[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value); 
}
```

This runs fine on my linux testing server (Cent OS 5.5) however, when it is transferred to the production environment (Windows Server 2003, IIS6 :( ) it blocks some SQL queries. Wondered if anyone else had run in to the same problem and knew of a solution.
Cheers

Comment: Exactly what does "blocks" mean?

Comment: And how exactly did you identify this part of the code as the culprit?

Comment: Remember that for `mysql_real_escape_string` to work, you need a database connection to be open. Other than that, you need to give more details on what doesn't work. By the way, I don't think what you are doing is a good practice. Escaping input data should take place where it is inserted into the database.

Comment: had copied that block of code a line above my connection /facepalm. Cheers for finding the culprit anyway. As for best practice 9/10 scripts which include are inserting post data and others are selecting data using get variables which could be injected, hence why I make sure I escape.

Comment: Overwriting the superglobals this way could be considered poor practice, especially if you're going to be using "outside" library/modules which could be depending on the superglobals being "clean". Either save your escaped values into another array, or do the escaping when it actually comes time to building your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Pekka essentially. Had not initiated db connection prior to calling `mysql_real_escape_string`.